# github actions: EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl:command not supported

Tags: openssl, github-actions

I am trying to deploy a self-hosted runner within Centos 7.2 system. But I encountered the following problem:
Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:06089093:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl:command not supported.

2022-07-24 09:42:32Z: Runner connect error: error:06089093:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl:command not supported. Retrying until reconnected.

Answer (score 0):

after I upgrade openssl by:
yum install openssl
the problem is resolved.